# How to find all the files with setuid bit set?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to find all the files with setuid bit set without having to install all packages of ubuntu. Is there a database that contains such info so that I can lookup?

Comment: See `man find` command output.

Comment: Your question here is really hard to follow, but I think that you are looking for a database that is external to find all the permissions of all files that could be installed into Ubuntu?  I don't think one exists out there.

Comment: @Terrance yeah seems like I misread it :D Updated.

Answer (score 1):

For packages installed...

```
sudo find / -perm -4000 -type f -exec ls -l {} \; > /tmp/files_with_setuid.txt
```

- `-perm -4000` is the permission for setuid. `-perm -u=s` can also be used.
- `-type f` for only files; remove if directories need to be included
- `ls -l` show it as a long list
- and it is stored into the file /tmp/files_with_setuid.txt

You will get a couple of error notices from /proc and /run. 1st couple of files ...

```
more /tmp/files_with_setuid.txt 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 43088 sep 16  2020 /snap/core18/1997/bin/mount
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 64424 jun 28  2019 /snap/core18/1997/bin/ping
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44664 mrt 22  2019 /snap/core18/1997/bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 26696 sep 16  2020 /snap/core18/1997/bin/umount
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 76496 mrt 22  2019 /snap/core18/1997/usr/bin/chfn
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44528 mrt 22  2019 /snap/core18/1997/usr/bin/chsh
...
```

---

Script ([found it on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800188/list-of-valid-suid-sgid-executables-on-linux)) to download every package and check for `setuid`:

```
PKG=$(apt-cache search . | cut -f 1 -d ' ');
echo $PKG | xargs apt-get download;
F=(`find *.deb`); for i in ${F[@]};
do dpkg -c $i | cut -c 4- | grep ^s | cut -c 4- | cut -f 2 -d '.';
done | tee suid_root;
```

It does not install packages, only downloads them ... so you still do need plenty of disk space.

Comment: No. I don't want to install all the packages.

Comment: Would apt-file be an appropriate place to include the permission info besides just filenames?

Comment: Does this check which files on your system CURRENTLY have setuid bits, rather than which ones are supposed to? I accidentally wiped all the setuid bits in about half of my top level directories, so I have to figure out how to reset them. I guess the second method would work, but I don't currently have that disk space, and the biggest problems I've faced so far have been from core system program files, like /usr/bin/sudo, /bin/su, and /sbin/unix_chkpwd, though I also broke VirtualBox and GParted. Just uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox worked, though not the "apt reinstall" command.

Comment: Actually, it probably isn't fair to say it broke gparted. I mean that gparted just gives a "pkexec must be setuid root" error when I run it without sudo, instead of automatically giving me a log in prompt of telling me to run it with sudo, like it used to do. Reinstalling it doesn't change things. Unhelpfully, it doesn't tell me where "pkexec" is, though some other answers seem to indicate it's a package I might be able reinstall and set the setuid bit of when I install it.

Comment: Probably I just need to reinstall Ubuntu with the same packages https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallingSamePackages

Comment: @H.H  You can not reset the setuid easily. The easiest method is a reinstall without formatting.That will reset all permissions to default.

Comment: What do you mean by "without formatting". Do you mean without reformatting the partitions?

Comment: Yes you MOUNT all your partitions the same as they are now without checking the format  option. Only works when installing the same Ubuntu.